# How to load different view controllers based if URL is provided on start in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I have an app, it authenticates with Instagram using safari, and when it returns I want it to load table view right away, without the login view.
Here is what I do now:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    DVGViewController *myVC = [[DVGViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DVGViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.viewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myVC];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    // some code skipped
    UITableViewController *myTVC = [[DVGTableViewController alloc] init];
    self.viewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myTVC];
    return YES;
}
```

At the moment I still get first method to work every time, although second method is triggered too, since I get calculations from url with it and I know that. Why it doesn't load tableView I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an error. In second method I have never set window and rootViewController. Adding this code to second method helped.

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
```

method will call if you app is come fro m specific URl like from facebook auth or from safari then this method will call

Comment: Yes, It is getting called and all is good but I don't get UITableView to load, I get regular DVGViewController

Comment: in your method you can write condition to check url is match with given text then it's load other UIViewController.

Comment: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url

Comment: I already have the code there that should show tableview without any conditions and it still doesn't work

Comment: is your app is UINavigation base app?